# Why setting encapsulation to none in a child component affects parent component style?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to apply a css file to components located in a child component, by importing the css file within the child's css file, and to affect the nested components using: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

As a consequence, when encapsulation is set to none, not only will it affect the components that are nested within the child component, but it will also affect the parent component, as the CSS file that has been imported will now also be applied to the parent component as well.

In my opinion, it makes no sense why setting encapsulation to none in a child component would be able to affect the parent component in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#members) to none will result in the styles propagating across other modules and components, thus it might not be suitable if you only want them to be applied within the module, or the parent/child components.

If you wish to apply the CSS only for that component and its 'nested' child components, you can try defining a shared css, which will be shared amongst the main component and the child component. Do not set ViewEncapsulation to None. This is how you can structure the files within that module.

```
|--parent
   |--shared
      |-- shared.css
   |--components
      |--child
         |--child.component.ts
         |--child.component.css
   |--parent.module.ts
   |--parent.component.ts
   |--parent.component.html
   |--parent.component.css
```

Then on the @Component type decorators near the top of both of your parent and child component, you can include the relative/absolute path of the css files required. As you can see, `shared.css` is included in both components, and the styles will only be encapsulated to these compenents.

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css', '../../shared/shared.css'],
})
```

And on your parent.component.ts,

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css', './shared/shared.css'],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Because they become global styles to your app. Depending on how you specify your CSS selectors and classes inside the component that has its `encapsulation` changed to `ViewEncapsulation.None`, they'll be applied to all the components in your application.

Comment: Aren't them become global only for child compoment and downward? and if not, is it possible to do so otherwise?

Comment: You'll have to use CSS classes to restrict the application of the styles. For example, you can impose that the styles will be valid only to components that have an specific other CSS class (and you can apply it to all the components you wish to receive the styles)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing topic for me. ViewEncapsulation.Emulated which is the default says that it will be parent to child. Still, in one of the child components, I override .mat-form-field-label there in its css file (the parent declaration for this is in the global styles.scss in angular.json) but it does not work. It does not get overridden.

It only works if i Use ViewEncapsulation.None with the css override or ::ng-deep. But these two applies it to the whole application right? Somehow, I even think they have a bug.